# Trying to read contents of a file, but failing? What's wrong with this code?

Tags: python, file

I'm new to python and have been learning it for almost 4 months now. A few days ago, I decided to try to make a small mailing system. Just to learn Files. I tried reading the contents of the file, but the program just closes.

Here's the code:

```
    def userlogin():
        f1 = open("user.txt","r")
        name1 = raw_input("Enter username: ")
        s1 = f1.readlines()
        print s1
```

I have called the function after that. Also, I have a file created with stuff written in them. I also tried the read() and readline() functions, but it doesn't seem to work. As soon as the program reaches this stage, it asks for Username..and then abruptly closes the window. Can anyone help me?

Comment: How do you launch your script?

Comment: Instead of 'doubleclicking' teh script (as I assume you're doing), open it from an IDE or console/shell using `python script.py`.

Comment: try to add `raw_input('press enter...')` after `print s1`.

Comment: OK....I'll try them and get back. Thanks! :)

Comment: Ok, I tried opening from the Shell...and that worked. Also, the "raw_input('Enter')" thing worked for when I'm opening by double-clicking the script. :) Thanks to all of you! :)

Comment: As pointed out by @tglaria, I stronly recommend the use of an IDE. For your personal use, download [Pycharm Community edition.](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/download/) It is worth it.